# Weird load averages, want to downgrade firmware

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-os, firmware, rpi-update

I have a bunch of raspberry pis

Two of them show a `vcgencmd version` of (a Pi4, and a Pi3A):

```
Jul  4 2022 14:41:54
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version 01db5c05be1b3594c8f040ed7c1ac2748890c2c8 (clean) (release) (start)
```

Then my 3B+ shows:

```
Jul 18 2022 17:51:16
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version 253a5190bae68b1b89d5da507c4017666cdf2cc4 (clean) (release) (start)
```

The 3B+ is constantly running at 1.5+ load averages...

Can someone help me figure out how I can move the latter to the earlier firmware?

Comment: Sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479): *"constantly running at 1.5+ load"* <- X Y -> *"move the latter to the earlier firmware"*.  Have you checked a process monitor and system logs to see if there isn't actually something happening to account for the load average?

Comment: @goldilocks sorry it does sounds like that! - I've done usual triage, nothing showing in the logs, nothing in htop/top/iotop, CPU usage is fine, and previously this machine was responsive and great. I think I accidentally scripted an rpi-update on it and since then the DNS server it hosts has been sluggish. FWIW the execution load hasn't changed either

Comment: You tag rpi-update. Did you run it? Did you read the warning NOT to?

Comment: I don’t get the attitude @Milliways. Over on StackOverflow I always try to be helpful. Not judgemental. 

Isn’t this a hobbiest community? It’s a play Linux credit card computer, not a production EC2 instance. 

Any thanks for all the help folks. I’ve got it sorted now.

Comment: How did you sort it out? It would be nice if you could make a detailed answer. You could accept it also.